# Importing data from SQL Server to Access 2010

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to collect specific data from a series of tables in a SQL Server database and combine them together in a single table in Access using VBA.

I created a recordset in Access using a query that combines all the data using multiple UNION ALL statements.  My initial approach was to iterate through the recordset with something like:

```
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim SQL As String

cnn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" + SQLServerNameStr + ";Database=" + DBNameStr + ";Trusted_Connection=Yes"

SQL = "SELECT A, B, C FROM TableA UNION ALL SELECT D, E, F FROM TableB UNION ALL ..." // etc., etc., etc.

rs.Open SQL, cnn, adOpenForwardOnly

While Not rs.EOF
    CurrentDB().Execute ("INSERT INTO AccessTable VALUES ('" & rs("FieldA") & "', '" & rs("FieldB") & "', '" & rs("FieldC") &"')")
    rs.MoveNext
Wend
```

This all works, however, it is excruciatingly slow for approximately 20,000 records.  I am sure there is a better way ... probably by building the INSERT into the main query, however, I cannot wrap my head around how to do this when the data source is on a connection to SQL Server and the destination in the current database.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your VBA code for your execute statement is incorrect, how does this even run?

Comment: I was trying to simplify ... I didn't actaully cut and paste my code ... I was just looking at how many mistakes I make when trying to code without an editor correcting my syntax!!! ;)

Comment: I have edited the question to correct the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `DoCmd.TransferDatabase`* to transfer data from a SQL Server view, that queries the data the way you need it, into an Access table.

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "ODBC Database", _ 
"Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & SQLServerNameStr & ";Database=" & DBNameStr & _
";Trusted_Connection=Yes", acTable, "SomeSqlServerView", "AccessTable"
```

Hopefully the transfer database method does a good job of managing insertions and speeds up the import process.

---

*Changed my answer since batch updates don't work with Access 2010 as a data destination.

Comment: dbOptimisitcBatch / dbUpdateBatch are only supported for ODBCDirect workspaces ... can I open an native Access table in this way?

Comment: Ah, you're right, batch updates do not seem to be supported. Now that I'm thinking about it I was writing to SQL Server from a VB6 application.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used native tables so much, but I suspect the issue is related to inserting one at a time.

You might want to try doing the insert through SQL and doing 50 rows at a time or so.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try doing an Insert query instead creating a recordset? See this question:
[How to insert "Entire" DAO recordset into a table with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843017/how-to-insert-entire-dao-recordset-into-a-table-with-vba)

Comment: This is what I was hoping to do, but I cannot figure out how to wrap the SELECT query, which is on a SQL Server connection, inside the INSERT query that is on the CurrentDb()

Comment: INSERT INTO AccessTable (FieldA, FieldB, FieldC) SELECT (FieldA, FieldB, FieldC) FROM (SELECT A, B, C FROM TableA UNION ALL SELECT D, E, F FROM TableB UNION ALL ..." // etc., etc., etc.)

Comment: Maybe I am being think (it wouldn't be the first time) but I am going to run the query by calling CurrentDB().Execute so the INSERT will go into a table in the Access database, but how do I then tell the query that the SELECT statement is coming from the SQL Server using the ADODB (or some other type) connection, not the currentdb?

Comment: One way to do it would be to import all the source tables into your Access DB as linked tables, or even copy all the data across.